# Objectify and google cloud end point examples

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I'm trying to find some concrete examples with google cloud end points and objectify. I've already found some with either end-points or objectify but none that combines both of them.

Comment: IMO, Objectify and Endpoints in combination behave like you would expect. If you understood them individually you should be able to understand how to use them in combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem than you when I started to learn objectify and endpoints.

Here is a tuto from website (Sorry that's in french): http://blog.xebia.fr/2014/06/23/google-app-engine-cloud-endpoint-creer-notre-api-v2-et-lutiliser-avec-angularjs/

**EDIT:**
You can find in english, this amazing website which explain in details my code below : http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/

In simple, you have to have three classes:

**Your object :**

```
@Entity
@Index

public class User {


        @Id private String num_portable; 
        private Boolean sexe;
        private int date_naissance;

        //Constructeur par défaut (Obligatoire pour Objectify)
        public User(){}

        public User (String num_portable, Boolean sexe, int date_naissance){

            this.num_portable=num_portable; //Numéro de portable user
            this.sexe=sexe; 
            this.date_naissance=date_naissance; 

        }

        /**
         * GETTER     
         */

        public String getId(){
            return num_portable;
        }
        public String getNum_portable() {
            return num_portable;
        }

        public Boolean getsexe(){
            return sexe;
        }

        public int getdate_naissance(){
            return date_naissance;
        }     


        /**
         * SETTER     
         */


        public void setsexe(Boolean sexe){
            this.sexe=sexe;
        }

        public void setdate_naissance(int date_naissance){
            this.date_naissance=date_naissance;
        }      

}
```

**Your class to do CRUD operations:**

```
public class UserCRUD {

    private static UserCRUD user_crud = null;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserCRUD.class.getName());

    static {
          ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
    }

    private UserCRUD (){

    }

    public static synchronized UserCRUD getInstance() {
          if (null == user_crud) {
           user_crud = new UserCRUD();
          }
      return user_crud;
    }


    public User findUser(String NumeroPhone) {
          User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(NumeroPhone).now();      
          return user;
    }
}
```

**Your endpoint class, which called by your endpoint (when you generated endpoint API):**

```
@Api(

    name = "userendpoint",
    version = "v1"
 )
public class UserEndPoint { 

     @ApiMethod(name = "FindUser", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
     public User getUser(@Named("numero_portable") String NumPortable){
         return UserCRUD.getInstance().findUser(NumPortable);
     }
}
```

Hope that will help you,

Comment: A useful example is described in [here](http://rominirani.com/2014/08/26/gradle-tutorial-part-9-cloud-endpoints-persistence-android-studio/).